# Different way in constructing ajax data parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I was quite confused with constructing data parameter of ajax using ASP.NET MVC and Webform and need an explanation from stackoverflow community.

First scenario (passing javascript object literal as data parameter in ajax using MVC) Results: It worked

MVC Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Register(string Name, string Birthday, int Gender)
    {
        .
        .
        .
        return Json(message);
    }
```

Javascript Code:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Test/Register",
        method: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            Name:name,
            Birthday:birthday,
            Gender:gender
        }
    }).success(function (response) {
        alert(response);
    }).error(function (response) {
        alert(response);
    });
```

Second scenario (passing javascript object literal as a string as data parameter in ajax using MVC) Results: Cause error 500 (Internal Server Error)

Javascript Code:

```
    var name = $('#Name').val();
    var birthday = $('#Birthday').val();
    var gender = $('#Gender').val();
    var data = "{ Name:'" + name + "', Birthday:'" + birthday + "', Gender:'" + gender + "'}";

    $.ajax({
        url: "/Test/Register",
        method: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: data,
    }).success(function (response) {
        alert(response);
    }).error(function (response) {
        alert(response);
    });
```

Results were different when I tested it on ASP.NET Webforms

Third scenario (passing javascript object literal as a string as data parameter in ajax using Webforms) Results: It worked

Webform WebMethod

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static string Submit(string Name, String Salary)
    {
        return "Success";
    }
```

Javascript Code:

```
    var name = $("#Name").val();
    var salary = $("#Salary").val();
    var data = "{ Name:'" + name + "', Salary:'" + salary + "'}";
    $.ajax({
        url: '/WebForm3.aspx/Submit',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        method: 'POST',
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response)
        {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function (response)
        {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
```

Forth scenario (passing javascript object literal as data parameter in ajax using Webforms) Results: Cause error 500 (Internal Server Error)

```
    $.ajax({
        url: '/WebForm3.aspx/Submit',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            Name: name,
            Salary: salary
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response)
        {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function (response)
        {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
```

Questions:

1. Why?
2. Will the scenarios that worked here on jQuery's ajax also work on other javascript frameworks like angularJS's $http service?
3. I also saw some scenarios on the internet that constructs its ajax data parameter using '=' example:

   ```
   var reservation = { "CourseCode": courseCode.val().toString(), "Section": section.val().toString(), "DateFrom": dateF.toString(), "DateTo": dateT.toString(), "Schedule": reservations };

           $.ajax({
               url: '/ReserveSubject',
               type: 'POST',
               data: 'reservation=' + JSON.stringify(reservation),//Like this
   ```
4. Can anyone show more more ways to construct ajax data parameters aside from the scenarios above? It would also be much appreciated if someone could also show the most eloquent way of constructing data parameter.

No takers?

Comment: If you use your browser's Dev Tools' *Network* tab you can see exactly what jQuery has done with your data in each case. That is, you can see the format of the request body. (Also, don't forget to note the difference between the `$.ajax()` method's `contentType` and `dataType` parameters - the latter specifies the expected format of the *response*.)

Comment: I am aware of this.  My problem is the data parameter.  Why does the string work on webforms and not on MVC and why does the javascript object literal work on MVC and not webform?  And what about the mechanics of the '=' replacing the ':'?

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

documentation on jQuery's ajax `data` exerpts this:

> data Type: PlainObject or String or Array Data to be sent to the
>   server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string.
>   It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See processData option to
>   prevent this automatic processing. Object must be Key/Value pairs. If
>   value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key
>   based on the value of the traditional setting (described below).

so you can pass it, string, aray or plain object,, while in Angulars `data` you can pass only string|object

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

so that's not same as in your examples,, you'll have to adjust if you send arrays

Comment: It doesn't seem to be the case given my tested scenarios.  Though it would be helpful if someone could point out the mistakes on why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest reducing the number of parameters on your controller actions to a single model object like:

```
public class RegisterModel
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Birthday {get; set;}
    public int Gender {get; set;}
}
```

This is just good practice for clean code anyway.

And then in the client side you can have model builders which take the data you want to send and then send up this object instead of a bunch of parameters

Comment: Btw, does this work on webforms?  I have tried this on MVC.  Any answers for my questions?

Comment: This may be a good idea in a general sense, but it doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: Still waiting for takers.